# position_dodge not working in ggplot2 for bar spacing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set of species observed along a transect line. I have plotted this data in a bar graph in ggplot:

[image]

The problem is that I want to maintain the same spacing across all bars, even in species that are not observed at all treatment levels.

I have tried using geom_col(position=position_dodge(preserve = "single")) but it does not seem to work- it makes all the bars very slim and skews everything. Any other suggestions?

Here is my plotting code:

```
bar <- ggplot(data, aes(x =Species, fill=Treatment, y=pct)) +
       geom_col(position=position_dodge(0.8), width=0.8, color="black") +
       theme_bw() +
       scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 0.35))+
       ylab("Proportion of transects") +
       scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9)
bar
```

And here is my data set:

```
data <- structure(list(Species = structure(c(3L, 13L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 13L, 
3L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 
3L, 13L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 13L, 9L, 14L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 
3L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 
14L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 13L, 14L, 9L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 
13L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 13L, 9L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 
9L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 9L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
10L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("ACOD", "CUNN", "DOL", "FLOU", 
"LOB", "LUMP", "POUT", "PRIA", "RCRAB", "SCUL", "SKATE", "SRAV", 
"STAR", "URCH"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L
), levels = c("Control", "Reef", "Reef Adjacent"), class = "factor"), 
    Count = c(36L, 35L, 5L, 36L, 4L, 22L, 36L, 24L, 21L, 36L, 
    35L, 24L, 5L, 36L, 4L, 22L, 36L, 36L, 24L, 35L, 18L, 36L, 
    22L, 36L, 24L, 36L, 35L, 24L, 18L, 36L, 22L, 36L, 36L, 24L, 
    35L, 36L, 21L, 22L, 36L, 24L, 35L, 36L, 21L, 22L, 36L, 36L, 
    24L, 21L, 36L, 35L, 18L, 36L, 22L, 36L, 24L, 36L, 35L, 18L, 
    24L, 36L, 22L, 36L, 21L, 36L, 35L, 24L, 36L, 36L, 24L, 36L, 
    35L, 24L, 36L, 22L, 36L, 24L, 21L, 35L, 24L, 36L, 36L, 22L, 
    21L, 36L, 36L, 35L, 24L, 22L, 36L, 36L, 21L, 24L, 35L, 34L, 
    14L, 22L, 4L, 35L, 16L, 34L, 5L, 22L, 1L, 35L, 16L, 34L, 
    14L, 22L, 35L, 2L, 16L, 34L, 5L, 22L, 35L, 16L, 34L, 35L, 
    16L, 34L, 2L, 22L, 35L, 34L, 22L, 35L, 14L, 34L, 22L, 35L, 
    16L, 34L, 14L, 35L, 16L, 34L, 14L, 35L, 34L, 14L, 22L, 1L, 
    35L, 34L, 22L), pct = c(0.333333333333333, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.0462962962962963, 0.333333333333333, 0.037037037037037, 
    0.203703703703704, 0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 
    0.194444444444444, 0.333333333333333, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.222222222222222, 0.0462962962962963, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.037037037037037, 0.203703703703704, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.203703703703704, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.324074074074074, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.203703703703704, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.194444444444444, 0.203703703703704, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.194444444444444, 0.203703703703704, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 
    0.194444444444444, 0.333333333333333, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.203703703703704, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.324074074074074, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.203703703703704, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.194444444444444, 0.333333333333333, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.203703703703704, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.194444444444444, 
    0.324074074074074, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.203703703703704, 0.194444444444444, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.222222222222222, 0.203703703703704, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.194444444444444, 0.222222222222222, 
    0.324074074074074, 0.314814814814815, 0.12962962962963, 0.203703703703704, 
    0.037037037037037, 0.324074074074074, 0.148148148148148, 
    0.314814814814815, 0.0462962962962963, 0.203703703703704, 
    0.00925925925925926, 0.324074074074074, 0.148148148148148, 
    0.314814814814815, 0.12962962962963, 0.203703703703704, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.0185185185185185, 0.148148148148148, 0.314814814814815, 
    0.0462962962962963, 0.203703703703704, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.148148148148148, 0.314814814814815, 0.324074074074074, 
    0.148148148148148, 0.314814814814815, 0.0185185185185185, 
    0.203703703703704, 0.324074074074074, 0.314814814814815, 
    0.203703703703704, 0.324074074074074, 0.12962962962963, 0.314814814814815, 
    0.203703703703704, 0.324074074074074, 0.148148148148148, 
    0.314814814814815, 0.12962962962963, 0.324074074074074, 0.148148148148148, 
    0.314814814814815, 0.12962962962963, 0.324074074074074, 0.314814814814815, 
    0.12962962962963, 0.203703703703704, 0.00925925925925926, 
    0.324074074074074, 0.314814814814815, 0.203703703703704)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -145L), groups = structure(list(
    Treatment = structure(1:3, levels = c("Control", "Reef", 
    "Reef Adjacent"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        c(7L, 8L, 9L, 17L, 24L, 25L, 32L, 39L, 40L, 46L, 47L, 
        48L, 54L, 55L, 62L, 63L, 68L, 69L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 84L, 
        90L, 91L, 92L, 96L, 97L, 102L, 108L, 114L, 122L, 125L, 
        129L, 141L, 142L, 145L), c(1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
        13L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 33L, 34L, 
        35L, 41L, 42L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 64L, 
        65L, 66L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
        93L, 98L, 99L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 115L, 
        116L, 118L, 119L, 123L, 126L, 130L, 131L, 134L, 135L, 
        138L, 143L), c(4L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 22L, 23L, 30L, 
        31L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 52L, 53L, 60L, 61L, 
        67L, 73L, 74L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 88L, 89L, 94L, 95L, 100L, 
        101L, 106L, 107L, 112L, 113L, 117L, 120L, 121L, 124L, 
        127L, 128L, 132L, 133L, 136L, 137L, 139L, 140L, 144L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: This is a duplicate: try `position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")`.

Comment: As mentioned in my question I have already tried this and it did not work!

Comment: You mention `position_dodge`, the answer to the question I believe is a duplicate uses `position_dodge2`. Check if it solves your problem, if it does not I will reopen.

Comment: In addition to making sure you use `position_dodge2`, you seem to have duplicate row in the data you provided. Try getting rid of the duplicates with `ggplot(unique(data), aes(x =Species, fill=Treatment, y=pct))` or combine them in some other way. When I do that I get the desired output https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMEnq.png

Comment: I tried using position_dodge2 and unfortunately it is still not working for me. @MrFlick could you post the code that you used to create that plot?

Comment: Rui's solution and duplicate closure is correct. The problem you're having is that there are duplicate rows in your data. See `filter(data, Species == "URCH")` for example. You either need to use `stat_sum(geom = "bar", ...)`or use `distinct(data)` depending on which is correct. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5euS.png).

Comment: This is just a subset of my data- I have other columns such as day of the year in the full dataset, making the data I posted not duplicates. In the full data set, each value is unique and I am still not able to use position_dodge2

Comment: Well if the data posted in the question is not sufficient to replicate the exact problem, then there might be something else going on. The code that worked for me with the sample data is: `ggplot(unique(data), aes(x =Species, fill=Treatment, y=pct)) + geom_col(position=position_dodge2(0.8, preserve = "single"), width=0.8, color="black") + theme_bw() + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 0.35)) + ylab("Proportion of transects") + scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9)`

Comment: Unfortunately that code didn't work for me with the full dataset. Strange. Thanks for your suggestions!!